# Python 2 and 3 're.sub' inconsistency

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am writing a function to split numbers and some other things from text in python. The code looks something like this:

```
EN_EXTRACT_REGEX = '([a-zA-Z]+)'
NUM_EXTRACT_REGEX = '([0-9]+)'
AGGR_REGEX = EN_EXTRACT_REGEX + '|' + NUM_EXTRACT_REGEX

entry = re.sub(AGGR_REGEX, r' \1\2', entry)
```

Now, this code works perfectly fine in python3, but it does not work under python2 and get an "*unmatched group*" error.

The problem is, I need to support both versions, and I could not get it to work properly in python2 although I tried various other ways.

I am curious what could be the root of this problem, and is there any workaround for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that the problem might be that the regex pattern matches one ***or*** the other of the subpatterns `EN_EXTRACT_REGEX` and `NUM_EXTRACT_REGEX`, but not both.

When `re.sub()` matches the alpha characters in the first pattern it attempts to substitute the second group reference with `\2` which fails because only the first group matched - there is no second group.

Similarly when the digit pattern is matched there is no `\1` group to substitute and so this also fails.

You can see that this is the case with this test in Python 2:

```
>>> re.sub(AGGR_REGEX, r' \1', 'abcd')    # reference first pattern
 abcd
>>> re.sub(AGGR_REGEX, r' \2', 'abcd')    # reference second pattern
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
sre_constants.error: unmatched group
```

The difference must lie within the different versions of the regex engine for Python 2 and Python 3. Unfortunately I can not provide a definitive reason for the difference, however, there is a documented change in version 3.5 for [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) regarding unmatched groups:

> Changed in version 3.5: Unmatched groups are replaced with an empty string.

which explains why it works in Python >= 3.5 but not in earlier versions: unmatched groups are basically ignored.

---

As a workaround you can change your pattern to handle both matches as a single group:

```
import re

EN_EXTRACT_REGEX = '[a-zA-Z]+'
NUM_EXTRACT_REGEX = '[0-9]+'
AGGR_REGEX = '(' + EN_EXTRACT_REGEX + '|' + NUM_EXTRACT_REGEX + ')'
# ([a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+)

for s in '', '1234', 'abcd', 'a1b2c3', 'aa__bb__1122cdef', '_**_':
    print(re.sub(AGGR_REGEX, r' \1', s))
```

Output

```
 1234
 abcd
 a 1 b 2 c 3
 aa__ bb__ 1122 cdef
_**_
```